# Dynamics CRM 2011 report view can't be changed?

Tags: microsoft-dynamics-crm

I am trying to create a report for our CRM system but I am finding that I cannot change the page settings for it. If I export it to Excel I can tinker around with the results but I would rather that I change the actual report than have users manually change it.

While I want this changed I don't want to have to add some third-party software to do this.

That said does anyone have any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Comment: I haven't messed around with it, but have you looked in to the BIDS plugin that comes with the installation media. Have you also installed the Reporting Services portion of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked into BIDS yesterday but did not like what I found, it seemed to be a bit much work for editing a single report.
I instead opted to manually edit the report in notepad which did achieve desired results. It took some looking around but I was able to find the proper sections to edit.
Thanks for your help.